# Is it possible to add tools in the toolbar and designed in CSS in a ASP.net (C#) project?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I know this might sound kinda stupid, but is it possible to set buttons, textbox etc etc.. in toolbox in visual studio 2015. but making the design in CSS?

I know you can give the same button the exact style form with CssClass="yourclass". But was thinking for this, and google didn't help me much.

Comment: You can use CSS just as you would. ASP.Net controls render as HTML, so for example, an `<asp:Textbox>` renders as `<input type="text">`. Doing `input {}` in your CSS would manipulate the `<asp:TextBox>`.

Comment: @Santi Can you please give some more information? did not understand it all

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net controls render as HTML, so you can use CSS just as you would in any other circumstance.

**Using element-based selectors:**

```
input[type="text"] {
   color: red;
}

<asp:Textbox runat="server" Text="This text is red!"></asp:TextBox>
```

---

**Using ID selectors:**

If you wanted to use specific IDs, it gets slightly trickier. ASP.Net controls do not render with their assigned IDs. You can circumvent this by applying `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your ASP elements:

```
#myTextbox {
   color: red;
}

<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="myTextbox" ClientIDMode="static"></asp:TextBox>
```

It's important to note that you cannot use this for repeated elements (Gridview controls, repeater controls, etc), because element IDs must be *unique*.

---

**Using class selectors:**

Or, as you mentioned, you could use `CssClass`:

```
.textbox {
   color: red;
}

<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
```